# image alt attribute via css style sheet

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, image, alt

**Method 1:**

Traditionally I would include an image like this:

```
<img src="image.png" alt="image" />
```

And the `alt attribute` would be in their for 2 reasons:

1. Help Visitors with an image
2. SEO purposes. So bots and crawlers know what an image is, i.e. keywords.

**Method 2:**

However, if I was to include the image via a css style sheet:

*HTML*

```
<div class="image"></div>
```

*CSS*

```
.image {
background-image: url(images/products_partitioning.png);
}
```

Is there anyway to include the alt attribute via as seen in 'method 1', in 'method 2' for SEO purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

If the image is a background image, then it would not make sense for it to have alternate content (since it is, by definition, not content).

If the image is not a background image, then it should be included via an `<img>` element and not CSS.

(There are hacks involving having real content in an element, then setting fixed dimensions on that element along with a background image and `text-indent: -9999px`, but that's ugly and unsemantic (and also the reverse of what you've asked for)).